# Export printer data to excel and use macros to create toner notifications

Tags: vba, excel

I work in an IT office that supports multiple departments where each department has a group of 5+ different printers on their floor. We have a LAN site set up that shows when the printers are running low on toner. After we see a low toner notification, we backcheck the printer number against an excel spreadsheet that tells us which printer model it is and which type of toner refill it will need.

I was wondering if it would be possible to consolidate this process with an excel vba. I want to run a macro that checks the LAN site for low toner notifications, backchecks the printer model and refill information, and then spits out a msgbox stating which printers need which refills. This would save us from the tedious and monotonous task of manually clicking through and checking each printer.

If this is not possible, it would at least be nice to create a macro to simply show a msgbox stating how many "low toner" notifications there are.

I can give more details, but I want to at least know if such a thing is possible first. I am an intern with a problem that I believe can be solved via excel macros, but I have no experience with them. I have only a small amount of exposure to .NET programming. Any advice would be appreciated!

Started first on the msgbox notifications:

```
Sub InfoInputs()

    Dim strPrinterNumber As String
    Dim strTonerNumber As String

    strPrinterNumber = InputBox("Which printers are you servicing? (Please enter the full printer name i.e. ATL-15-14S220)", "Printer Selection")
    If strPrinterNumber = "" Then MsgBox "You need to enter a valid printer ID."
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If strPrinterNumber <> "" Then
        MsgBox "you chose: " & strPrinterNumber
            If strPrinterNumber = Range("E2:E30").Find(What:=strPrinterNumber, MatchCase:=True) Then
                 strTonerNumber = Range("F3:F30,G3:G30,H3:H30,I3:I30")
                MsgBox "You need: strTonerNumber"
             Else
                MsgBox "You need to enter a valid printer ID."
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a good initial idea. Start with that, and head on back when you run into a specific issue. I would also recommend taking a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - before posting again. Good luck!

Comment: When you say LAN site I assume you mean an internal web page? If so, you'll want to look at internet explorer automation through VBA or direct use of the winhttp library.

Comment: Thanks, admdrew! Sorry for the lengthy/poorly put together post. Someone just recommended me to the site and I just wanted to put a post up quickly before going out to lunch in case it was a quick solution. I'll be more careful now.

Blackhawk - I'm looking into your suggestion now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetPrinterAlert()
'Get Alert from Xerox WorkCentre
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;yourprinterurl/status/general.php", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "general"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    'get me the total rows output
irows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'loop thru the list
For i = irows To 2 Step -1
'code that start with 09 = toner needed.
If Left(Cells(i, 2).Value, 2) <> "09" Then
'do something with this row.

'09-565-00   The Magenta Toner (M) is near end of life. User intervention is required to reorder Magenta Toner; do not replace until prompted. Machine services are unaffected.
'09-566-00   The Cyan Toner (C) is near end of life. User intervention is required to reorder Cyan Toner; do not replace until prompted. Machine services are unaffected.

End If
Next i
End Sub
```